# Хранение изображения в БД

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms, ado.net

Есть локальное приложение на WinForms с пользовательскими данными. Данные хранятся в MySql. Мне нужно хранить фотографии каждого сотрудника в базе и отображать с данными сотрудника на DataGridView.

Теперь возникает вопрос, где лучше хранить данные? Как лучше реализовать?

В MySql создаю колонку с BLOB. На это ругается datagrid. Как реализовать такого рода приложение?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace LOCAL_PROJECT
{
    public partial class mary : Form
    {
        public mary()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        //CONNECTION STRING
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("sta");
       
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server = 192.168.1.199; UserId = admin; Password = 12345; database = telecom");
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        int id;
      
        MySqlCommand command;

        public void Spisok()
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(" SELECT * FROM `sta` ", con);
            DataSet dset = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dset);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
            con.Close();
        }
        
        private void Mary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Spisok();
            dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lime;
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = 35;
            dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 40;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 95;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 120;
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 70;
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Width = 70;
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].Width = 70;
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].Width = 66;
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].Width = 73;
            dataGridView1.Columns[8].Width = 70;
            dataGridView1.Columns[9].Width = 50;
            dataGridView1.Columns[10].Width = 50;

            dataGridView1.Columns[11].Width = 50;
            dataGridView1.Columns[12].Width = 50;
            dataGridView1.Columns[13].Width = 50;
            dataGridView1.Columns[14].Width = 50;
            dataGridView1.Columns[15].Width = 58;
            dataGridView1.Columns[16].Width = 58;
            dataGridView1.Columns[17].Width = 58;
            dataGridView1.Columns[18].Width = 58;
            dataGridView1.Columns[19].Width = 68;
          //  dataGridView1.Columns[20].Width =75;
          

            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Value = "Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Value = "Type";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderCell.Value = "yaer";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderCell.Value = "prefix";
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderCell.Value = "size";
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderCell.Value = "free size";
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderCell.Value = "Internet size";
            dataGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderCell.Value = "freesizeint";
            dataGridView1.Columns[9].HeaderCell.Value = "workintnumber";
            dataGridView1.Columns[10].HeaderCell.Value = "abonplata";
            dataGridView1.Columns[11].HeaderCell.Value = "dslam48";
            dataGridView1.Columns[12].HeaderCell.Value = "dslam128";
            dataGridView1.Columns[13].HeaderCell.Value = "dslam288";
            dataGridView1.Columns[14].HeaderCell.Value = "dslam896";
            dataGridView1.Columns[15].HeaderCell.Value = "kabel30";
            dataGridView1.Columns[16].HeaderCell.Value = "kabel50";
            dataGridView1.Columns[17].HeaderCell.Value = "kabel100";
            dataGridView1.Columns[18].HeaderCell.Value = "kabel200";
            
            dataGridView1.Columns[19].HeaderCell.Value = "responsible officer";
           
            DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            imageColumn = (DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[20];
            imageColumn.Name = "IMAGE";
            imageColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;


            // SUM 
            textBoxSum.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows where row.Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
            textBoxSumbosgowrum.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows where row.Cells[6].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[6].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
            textBoxSumInternet.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows where row.Cells[7].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[7].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
          
            textBoxSumBosInternet.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows where row.Cells[8].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[8].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();



        }

        private void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
        {
            Spisok();
            con.Open();
            command = con.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = txtQuery;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            menu menuu = new menu();
            menuu.Show();
        }

        // Метод автонумерация ID
        private DataTable AutoNumberedTable(DataTable SourceTable)

        {
            DataTable ResultTable = new DataTable();
            DataColumn AutoNumberColumn = new DataColumn
            {
                ColumnName = "id",
                DataType = typeof(int),
                AutoIncrement = true,
                AutoIncrementSeed = 1,
                AutoIncrementStep = 1
            };
            ResultTable.Columns.Add(AutoNumberColumn);
            ResultTable.Merge(SourceTable);
            return ResultTable;
        }
          
        private void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
       


            string sql = "insert into sta (id, name, satstype, year, prefix, size, freesize, internet_size, freesizeint, workintnumber, abonplata, dslam48, dslam128, dslam288, dslam896, kabel30, kabel50, kabel100, kabel200, montyor, image) Values (null, '" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + comboBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', " +
                "'" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "', '" + textBox5.Text + "', '" + textBox6.Text + "', '" + textBox7.Text + "',  '" + textBox8.Text + "', '" + comboBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox9.Text + "', '" + textBox10.Text + "', '" + textBox11.Text + "', '" + textBox12.Text + "', '" + textBox13.Text + "', '" + textBox14.Text + "', '" + textBox15.Text + "', '" + textBox16.Text + "', '" + textBox17.Text + "', '" + Path.GetFileName(pictureBox2.ImageLocation) + "')";
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = AutoNumberedTable(dt);
            
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            File.Copy(textBox18.Text, Application.StartupPath + @"\Image\" + Path.GetFileName(pictureBox2.ImageLocation));
            MessageBox.Show("Added!");
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            comboBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox3.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox4.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox5.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox6.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox7.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox9.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox10.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox11.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox12.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox13.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox14.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox15.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox8.Text = string.Empty;
            comboBox2.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox17.Text = string.Empty;
        
            Spisok();  // метод коннектит базой данных 

           

        }

        // Метод делете
        private void Delete(int id)
        {
            string sql = "DELETE FROM sta WHERE tb=" + id + "";
            command = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

            //OPEN CON, EXECUTE DELETE, CLOSE CON

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command)
                {
                    DeleteCommand = con.CreateCommand()
                };
                adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = sql;

                // PROMT FOR CONFIRMATION

                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Deleted!");
                }

                con.Close();

                Spisok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        //Delete button
        private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selected = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            int tb = Convert.ToInt32(selected);
            Delete(id);
        }
        
        private void DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());

                id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
               // Byte[] img = (Byte[])dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[20].Value;

              //  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
             //   pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

                textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                comboBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                textBox7.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                textBox8.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                textBox9.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
                textBox10.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
                textBox11.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
                textBox12.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
                textBox13.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
                textBox14.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[16].Value.ToString();
                textBox15.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value.ToString();
                textBox16.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[18].Value.ToString();
                
               
                comboBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
                textBox17.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[19].Value.ToString();
               
                

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                con.Close();
            }
        }

       private void TextBox13_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = "Select * From sta where name like '%" + textBox21.Text + "%' OR satstype like '%" + textBox21.Text + "%' OR prefix like '%" + textBox21.Text + "%' OR size like '%" + textBox21.Text + "%' OR freesize like '%" + textBox21.Text + "%' OR internet_size like '%" + textBox21.Text + "%' OR freesizeint like '%" + textBox21.Text + "%' OR potsplata like '%" + textBox21.Text + "%' OR dslam like '%" + textBox21.Text + "%' OR year like '%" + textBox21.Text + "%' OR geolocationC like '%" + textBox21.Text + "%' OR geolocationC like '%" + textBox21.Text + "%' OR geolocationB like '%" + textBox21.Text + "%'";
            DataSet dset = new DataSet();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.Fill(dset);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
            con.Close();
        } 

        private void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                command = new MySqlCommand("update sta SET name='" + textBox1.Text + "', satstype='" + comboBox1.Text + "',  year='" + textBox2.Text + "', prefix='" + textBox3.Text + "', size='" + textBox4.Text + "', freesize='" + textBox5.Text + "', internet_size='" + textBox6.Text + "', freesizeint='" + textBox7.Text + "',   WHERE tb='" + tb + "'", con);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Obnowit edildi!");
                con.Close();
                Spisok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }   
        

        private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            
            Openpage openpage = new Openpage();
           
            openpage.textBox1.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            openpage.textBox2.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            openpage.textBox3.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            openpage.textBox8.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
            openpage.textBox7.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
            openpage.textBox6.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
            openpage.textBox5.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
            openpage.textBox12.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
            openpage.textBox11.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[16].Value.ToString();
            openpage.textBox10.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value.ToString();
            openpage.textBox9.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[18].Value.ToString();
            openpage.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }



        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.Filter = "Choose Image(*.JPG; *.PNG; *.GIF) | *.jpg; *.png; *.gif";
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap(dialog.FileName);
                pictureBox2.ImageLocation = dialog.FileName;
                pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у Вас данные в DataGrid загуржаются как? Там в DataGridView должен быть тип столбца Image, чтобы DataGridView мог показать картинку на этом месте. И нужно в этот столбец перекладывать тот BLOB, который лежит в таблице. Думаю, что без кода, который у Вас написан, вам более подробно вряд ли кто то подскажет.

Comment: данные через грид текстбокс вводится в базу данных , после отображается в гриде с помощью CellMouseClick. теперь при добавлении данных нужно подкреплять фотографию для каждой строки данных .

Comment: Изображения лучше вообще не хранить в БД, загружайте файлы в папку и генерируйте им название с помощью ```Guid```, а сам ```Guid``` уже храните в БД как ```Id``` файла в директории. **Не уверен**, но ```blob``` в C# будет как ```byte[]```. Если выгружать изображение с БД как ```blob```, то будет высокая нагрузка.

Comment: тоесть лучше извлекать изображение с компьютера сервера ?  допустим приложение по локальной сети использует 10 человек и все 10 человек могут добавлять и просматривать данные с изображениями.  допустим есть локальный сервер Wamp на одном компьютере через этот сервер управляется базы данных

Comment: У вас сколько сотрудников? Если вы полноценную файлопомойку делать не собираетесь для картинок, а просто будете хранить по одной фотке профиля для человека, спокойно храните в бд это все и не парьтесь.

Comment: исключительно не файл-помойка , всего 30 сотрудников , и для каждого сотрудника по фотографию на профиль. вопрос где лучше хранить фотографию , если на базе данных , то каким образом хранить , в одной таблице с другими данными ?

Comment: Давайте по порядку. После выполнения метода `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` данные сохраняются в БД?

Comment: Что делает метод `Spisok()`? Читает данные из БД и загружает в грид?

Comment: Покажите код загрузки данных из БД.

Comment: извиняюсь что поздно пишу вам ,  нет не храниться данные в БД,  метод список подключение к БД таблицу грид, выше выложил весь код

Comment: можете помочь ?